# oracle.dataaccess invalid username/password

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I am having a asp.net web application in which I am connecting to a Oracle DB using oracle.DataAccess component. My DBA created a new account and when I try to login with that account in toad, it simply worked fine but when I am passing the values in connection string in SERVER A it is giving me invalid username/password. I double checked the credentials and they are correct. Then I copied the entire website into a new SERVER B and when i tried, I am able to login to the oracle DB. I am very much confused about whats happening. Any Ideas? Is it possible to enable any trace on my servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version (Oracle DB and Oracle.DataAccess) do you use?

In Oracle 11 passwords are case-sensitive (by default), in prior version it was not. Thus Oracle.DataAccess version earlier than 11 may have problems dealing properly with case sensitive passwords.