# Oracle 11.2.0: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied when connecting from C#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle11g, odp.net

I get the following exception when I try to connect to my Oracle 11.2.0 database from my Visual Studio 2019 application:

> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

code:

```
var connection = new DbConnection("UserName", "pswd", "DBTNSdatasource");
```

I am passing it in a constructor which further establishes the connection in some referenced base class, however I am getting the error ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied.

I have two oracle client installed 11.2.0 and 12.1.0 (used in a different project) and using
Assembly Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0

When I use SQL Developer I am able to connect to the same database with same credentials and perform any query. Any idea ?

Comment: Please show us the code of the constructor. The error you get is pretty clear. In Oracle <11g the password was not case-sensitive by default. Try the Oracle.DataAccess version 12.1, perhaps the old one makes the password in upper-cases.

Comment: Could it be *mixed* letter case? Did you provide username and password exactly as they really are?

Comment: See also  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22039966/3027266

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit unfortunately don't have an access to the code inside constructor. I will try after updating Oracle.DataAccess version 12.1. However I have one different project solution where m using same Oracle.DataAccess version & oracle 11.2.0 there it is getting connected without any error only difference there is that i am connecting through basic connection strng <add key="DSN" value="Password=pswd;User ID=UserName;Data Source=DBTNSdatasource"/> but in the above problem i dont knw how the connection is established since have no access to constructor code.